# How to get status of radio buttons

Tags: php

Please how can I get the status of radio buttons based on their value in the database?
I want to set them to either checked or unchecked based on their respective values in the database. field_type is int(1 or 0).
Is there a more efficient way to do this?

$news_alert_status_a = "unchecked";
        $news_alert_status_k = "unchecked";
        $news_alert_status_n = "unchecked";

```
    $events_alert_status_a = "unchecked";
    $events_alert_status_k = "unchecked";
    $events_alert_status_n = "unchecked";

    $questions_alert_status_a = "unchecked";
    $questions_alert_status_k = "unchecked";
    $questions_alert_status_n = "unchecked";

    $editorials_alert_status_a = "unchecked";
    $editorials_alert_status_k = "unchecked";
    $editorials_alert_status_n = "unchecked";


    if ($news_alert == 1)
    {
        $news_alert_status_a = "checked";
    }
    elseif ($news_alert == 2)
    {
        $news_alert_status_k = "checked";
}
elseif($news_alert == 3)
{
    $news_alert_status_n = "checked";
}


if ($events_alert == 1)
    {
        $events_alert_status_a = "checked";
    }
    elseif ($events_alert == 2)
    {
        $events_alert_status_k = "checked";
}
elseif($events_alert == 3)
{
    $events_alert_status_n = "checked";
}

if ($questions_alert == 1)
    {
        $questions_alert_status_a = "checked";
    }
    elseif ($questions_alert == 2)
    {
        $questions_alert_status_k = "checked";
}
elseif($questions_alert == 3)
{
    $questions_alert_status_n = "checked";
}       

if ($editorials_alert == 1)
    {
        $editorials_alert_status_a = "checked";
    }
    elseif ($editorials_alert == 2)
    {
        $editorials_alert_status_k = "checked";
}
elseif($editorials_alert == 3)
{
    $editorials_alert_status_n = "checked";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The PHP code:

<?PHP

$male_status = 'unchecked';
$female_status = 'unchecked';

if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {

$selected_radio = $_POST['gender'];

if ($selected_radio = = 'male') {
$male_status = 'checked';
}
else if ($selected_radio = = 'female') {
$female_status = 'checked';
}
}

?>

The HTML FORM code:

<FORM name ="form1" method ="post" action ="radioButton.php">

<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='gender' value= 'male'
<?PHP print $male_status; ?>
>Male

<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='gender' value= 'female'
<?PHP print $female_status; ?>
>Female

<P>
<Input type = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Select a Radio Button">
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
 if($_POST['gender'] != "")
 {
  $gender = $_POST['gender'] == "male" ? 1 : 0;
 }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Radio Button</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
<label for="radio_female">Female</label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="radio_female" value="female"/>
<label for="radio_male">Male</label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="radio_male" value="male"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```